# How to enocode an output file in snowflake?

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to unload a JSON file in S3.The output always has nbsp characters.

I assumed it could be fixed with encoding but going through the documentation shows snowflake only supports UTF-8 encoding for JSON.
Is there are way to change the encoding?
Rather any other ways to handle the nbsp ?